# SSIS package with various data flows; table loads randomly fail

Tags: ssis

I currently face a problem with an SSIS package that is part of a multiple-step ETL job that is launched every night. This SSIS package is used for Staging, so bringing data from Views on a remote SQL server into tables a local SQL server. The data is originally coming from an ERP system.

## Description of the SSIS package

The SSIS package contains one single container. In that container, you will a lot of of "task-pairs". With a "task-pair" I mean a combination of an Execute SQL Task as well as a Data Flow task. The Execute SQL Task truncates the data tables in the destination database, whereas the Data Flow task, "re-loads" the appropriate tables.

The tables that are loaded, are "clustered". So there is a "task-pair" for e.g. all tables related to Sales. The Execute SQL Task truncates all Sales related tables, whereas the Data Flow task loads all tables related to Sales.

All "task-pairs" in the container in this SSIS package may be started in parallel. So there's no sequence defined.

The SSIS package runs on a SQL server which is on premise. It is the same server that hosts the destination tables of the Staging. The data is pulled from another SQL server in the same corporate network but not in the same LAN, so accessed over VPN connection.

## Problem description

Since a few days, some of the Data Flow tasks that load data from various tables in the source into the destination fail. More specifically, not the whole Data Flow task fail, only some of the tables that are loaded within that task fail.

So for example: let's say the Data Flow task that loads all tables related to Sales, loads in total 10 tables. Sometimes all 10 tables are staged successfully, sometimes tables 1,2 and 8 fail, sometimes table 3 fails etc. Failing by the way does not mean that the target table is empty after the error occured. It just means, that not all records were transferred.

Funny thing is... the error occurs randomly, I am not able to identify a pattern, well perhaps that the bigger tables with more records in it, tend to fail more often than the smaller ones with less records.

I checked the error messages on the server and I get the following ones.... I get two error messages for each view that failed to be staged.

`Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The PrimeOutput method on "View Name in Source" returned error code 0xC0202009. The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.`

and right below another error message... that refers to the same view

`Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has oncurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Protocol error in TDS stream". An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Protocol error in TDS stream". An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Protocol error in TDS stream".`

Nothing was changed, neither on the source server, nor on the destination server. We still use SQL Native Client 11 for accessing both servers.

Any idea what could be the root cause of this issue?
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

What I already tried is....

- launch the whole package directly from Visual Studio 2019 -> same result, some tables in some of the Data Flow tasks fail; i retry the specific Data Flow Task manually and the load finishes successful
- make a copy ofthe whole project and switch the connection managers to from SQL Native Client 11 to Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server -> seems to be more stable but still some tables fail, retrying them usually succeeds
- In the SQL server on the source server it looks as if the connection breaks in the middle of the transfer, but there are no other indicators in the logs

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! The SSIS package runs on a SQL server which is on premise. It is the same server that hosts the destination tables of the Staging. The data is pulled from another SQL server in the same corporate network but not in the same LAN, so accessed over VPN connection. Does that clarify the setup? Thanks

Comment: Given the transient nature, it sure *smells* like network issues. Especially with "retrying them usually succeeds" Perhaps someone has changed something in the routing between servers, fiddled with the VPN, etc. Hard to say and definitely hard to reproduce for the folks of SO to provide an authoritative answer. Or the source server is getting busy during the package runs and things start going pear shaped.

Comment: Yes, to me it also looks like a connection issue. However, we checked here and there, unable to find something. I know, it is almost impossible to say, bit do you think it could be caused by a high load on the server? Like too much running in parallel? Maybe it's worth, trying to not load everything in parallel to see if this makes a difference or not. Even though this has never been a problem in years

Comment: Maybe or maybe it's things outside of your normal scope, like hardware routers and firewalls and junk like that

Comment: Unfortunately the error messages in SSIS are really vague. I will change the package so that data is loaded more sequentially. I will give feedback if this has any effect or not. Besides that I have no clue how to fix this. Network and SQL traces do not show anything relevant

Comment: So here's a short feedback from my side. After re-designing the package so that not so many data flows are launched in parallel, the package succeeds. Of course overall it is slower than before but more stable.

Answer (score 0):

I advocate for packages being either a worker or an orchestrator/controller pattern. If I have 2 facts and dimensions in my warehouse, then I have 11 packages.

Workers are restartable without manual correction of data. Either they are atomic and commit all in a big batch or they use some high watermark/breadcrumb/etc or they use lookups to determine what data to load. In your case, think about your Sales loader as a worker (or potentially many workers as they may be loading the dimensions necessary for a Fact Sales loader).

Controllers focus on the sequencing of workers. Run the Dimension Package before running the Fact packages. These N packages can run at the same time as there's no dependencies between them.  Ultimately, this works out to something like the following

[image]

Assume you have a table that contains information about controllers, workers and the execution ordering.

```
ControllerPackage   | ChildPackage      | WorkBucket  | WorkOrder
SalesWarehouse.dtsx | DimDate.dtsx      | D0          |  10
SalesWarehouse.dtsx | DimPerson.dtsx    | D0          |  20
SalesWarehouse.dtsx | DimProduct.dtsx   | D1          |  10
SalesWarehouse.dtsx | DimCustomer.dtsx  | D2          |  10
SalesWarehouse.dtsx | DimWarehouse.dtsx | D1          |  20
SalesWarehouse.dtsx | FactSales.dtsx    | F3          |  10
SalesWarehouse.dtsx | FactSnapshot.dtsx | F3          |  20
```

- Create a Sequence container called Loader
- Create a variable called LoaderPrefix and assign it a value of D
- Click the move variable to move it from the Canvas to our Sequence container
- Add a sequence container inside Loader called Do Work 0
- Add a variable of type Int32, BucketNumber, and then move it to the "Do Work 0" container
- Add a variable of type String, BucketName, and move it to the "Do Work 0" container.
- Select Do Work 0 and navigate to the Variables. Click the Expression for BucketName and make it `@[User::LoaderPrefix] + ((DT_WSTR, 1)  @[User::BucketNumber])`
- Add a variable of type String, CurrentPackage, and move it to the "Do Work 0" container.
- Add a variable of type Object, rsPackages, and move it to the "Do Work 0" container.
- Inside Do Work 0, add an Execute SQL Task. Use something like `SELECT WP.ChildPackage, WP.WorkOrder FROM dbo.WorkPile AS WP WHERE WP.ControllerPackage = ? AND WP.WorkBucket = ? ORDER BY WP.WorkOrder;` Plumb in variables `[System::PackageName]` and `@[User::BucketName]` (note, the supplied sample doesn't work as the System::PackageName variable does not contain the file extension .dtsx  Choose Full Result Set as the option and load to `rsPackages`
- Inside Do Work 0, add a ForEach Loop Container. On the Collection tab, change to a Foreach ADO Enumerator and select our rsPackages. On the Variable Mapping tab, associate Variable @[User::CurrentPackage] to index 0
- Inside your Foreach Loop Container , add an Execute Package Task and use expressions to point it at the @[User::CurrentPackage] value

Wow, that's a lot! But not really and you'll see the benefits shortly. Debug the package, make sure it all works as expected for WorkBucket d0 and you should see 2 packages run, DimDate then DimPerson.

Assuming that's all good, we're going to use the secret productivity multiplier: copy and paste. I copy the "Do Work 0" object and click the "Loaders" container to set the correct context and then paste away. I'll now have "Do Work 0", "Do Work 0 1", ... "Do Work 0 4"

- Rename each task to remove the 0 from the name
- Select the task and update the value of BucketNumber to match the name, 0 to 1, 0 to 2, etc

Now if you run it, you should see all five workers light up and run any packages associated to them. This gets us a nice mix of serial execution and parallelism. If you find a Dimension is very slow/large, put it in its own worker container, let it do its thing while all the little bees are buzzing about taking care of their tasks.

Ready for Facts which depend on the dimensions? Copy and paste but this time, we're going to copy the existing Loader container. Select the background of the canvas and paste. Connect the Green arrow from the "Loader" to "Loader 1"

- Rename both Loaders so we know what we're dealing with
- Click Fact Loaders and change the value of @[User::LoaderPrefix] from "D" to "F"

If this pattern solves your needs, you now have a generic orchestrator. Copy paste it for Shipping warehouse loader or Marketing. Since it's based on the file name and values in tables, it's super flexible. If you discover you are getting those weird errors resources, update your controller table values to make things go more Serial and less Parallel. Want it to finish sooner, try enabling another worker bucket (in this example, Do Work 3 and 4 start up, identify there is no work to be done for them and finish)